# Search Engine - rank the output by a weighted mechanism

Tags: python, tensorflow, elasticsearch, word-embedding, sentence-similarity

I am trying to build a semantic search FAQ system using Elastic 7.7.0 and Universal Sentence Encoder (USE4) word embeddings, so far i have indexed a set of question and answers, which i am able to search. I am doing 2 searches whenever there is input :

1. key word search on elastic on indexed data
2. Semantic search using USE4 embeddings

Now i want to combine both to give the robust output, because sometimes results are off from these individual algorithms. Any good suggestions on how can i combine them? use the weighted mechanism to give more weight to Semantic search, and/or be able to match them again. Question is how do i get best of both. Please advise.

```
import time
import sys
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk
import csv
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

def connect2ES():
    # connect to ES on localhost on port 9200
    es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
    if es.ping():
            print('Connected to ES!')
    else:
            print('Could not connect!')
            sys.exit()

    print("*********************************************************************************");
    return es

def keywordSearch(es, q):
    #Search by Keywords
    b={
            'query':{
                'match':{
                    "title":q
                }
            }
        }

    res= es.search(index='questions-index_quora2',body=b)
    print("Keyword Search:\n")
    for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
        print(str(hit['_score']) + "\t" + hit['_source']['title'] )

    print("*********************************************************************************");

    return


# Search by Vec Similarity
def sentenceSimilaritybyNN(embed, es, sent):
    query_vector = tf.make_ndarray(tf.make_tensor_proto(embed([sent]))).tolist()[0]
    b = {"query" : {
                "script_score" : {
                    "query" : {
                        "match_all": {}
                    },
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'title_vector') + 1.0",
                        "params": {"query_vector": query_vector}
                    }
                }
             }
        }


    #print(json.dumps(b,indent=4))
    res= es.search(index='questions-index_quora2',body=b)

    print("Semantic Similarity Search:\n")
    for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
        print(str(hit['_score']) + "\t" + hit['_source']['title'] )

    print("*********************************************************************************");



if __name__=="__main__":

    es = connect2ES();
    embed = hub.load("./data/USE4/") #this is where my USE4 Model is saved.


    while(1):
        query=input("Enter a Query:");

        start = time.time()
        if query=="END":
            break;

        print("Query: " +query)
        keywordSearch(es, query)
        sentenceSimilaritybyNN(embed, es, query)

        end = time.time()
        print(end - start)
```

My output looks like this:

```
Enter a Query:what can i watch this weekend
Query: what can i watch this weekend
Keyword Search:

9.6698  Where can I watch gonulcelen with english subtitles?
7.114256    What are some good movies to watch?
6.3105774   What kind of animal did this?
6.2754908   What are some must watch TV shows before you die?
6.0294256   What is the painting on this image?
6.0294256   What the meaning of this all life?
6.0294256   What are your comments on this picture?
5.9638205   Which is better GTA5 or Watch Dogs?
5.9269657   Can somebody explain to me how to do this problem with steps?
*********************************************************************************
Semantic Similarity Search:

1.6078881   What are some good movies to watch?
1.5065247   What are some must watch TV shows before you die?
1.502714    What are some movies that everyone needs to watch at least once in life?
1.4787409   Where can I watch gonulcelen with english subtitles?
1.4713362   What are the best things to do on Halloween?
1.4669418   Which are the best movies of 2016?
1.4554278   What are some interesting things to do when bored?
1.4307204   How can I improve my skills?
1.4261798   What are the best films that take place in one room?
1.4175651   What are the best things to learn in life?
*********************************************************************************
0.05920886993408203
```

i want one output which is based on both of these, where we can get more accurate results and rank them accordingly too. Please advise or redirect where i can refer some good practices around this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This seems far too broad/vague. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].